# Can't add puppeteer library inside the NodeJs firebase initialised project?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, node-modules

I created firebase cloud function project using `firebase init` then i tried to add the `puppeteer` using `npm install pupeteer` but it is creating a separate **node modules** outside the functions. What went wrong here, Why i can't add puppeteer library inside function node modules?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we init the NodeJS project with firebase CLI, `index.js` file will be come inside the functions folder with node modules(like in the mention image above).
So in order to add any other libraries **we have to navigate to the function folder and then we want to add our libraries** . in the question we have to add pupeteer library so

```
npm install --save puppeteer
```

So, puppeteer library will save with firebase Node modules. there will not be two node modules.